# Cannot create model instance in Django using an object manager

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django noob i should say! I have created a DeveloperManager() manager class and a Developer() model class.
I am trying to create a developer record in the database using

```
d = Developer.objects.create_default_developer("a test name", "username", "1234", "email@example.com")
```

But it fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/project/engine/models.py", line 9, in create_default_developer
    def create_default_developer(self, developer_name, username, password, email):
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: create() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)
```

What is actually going wrong here? I think i have correctly set all parameter's but this still fails.

My code is as following:

```
class DeveloperManager(models.Manager):

    def create_default_developer(self, developer_name, username, password, email):
        developer = self.create(developer_name=developer_name, username=username, password=password, email=email)
        return developer


class Developer(models.Model):

    developer_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    billing_email = models.EmailField()
    created = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated')


    @classmethod
    def create(cls, developer_name, username, password, email):
        developer = cls(developer_name, username, password, email)
        developer.save()
        return developer

    objects = DeveloperManager()
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: using `developer = Developer(developer_name=developer_name, username=username, password=password, email=email)` in the `create_default_developer()`, it successfully creates the object. But is this a correct way of using managers? If it is, am totally okay with that. If it's not, what should i do to correctly use the django managers?

Comment: The `self.create(..)` in `DeveloperManager` calls `models.Manager.create(..)` and not `Developer.create(..)` which it looks like you want it to...

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match up with the code; it is not the `def create_default_developer(self, developer_name, username, password, email):` that can throw this exception. **Restart** Django to pick up the changes you made.

Comment: @thebjorn that's true but note that the base Manager class already defines a create method which does what OP wants, so the Model classmethod is irrelevant anyway and the error is somewhere else.